# What search level is possible in chess using only one thread and no pruning, reductions, extensions or assembly language

Tags: performance, chess

The C#.NET program used negascout which is a variant of alfa beta search and the maximal level is 6 or 7 when CPU time is limited to 30 seconds. Level 0 contains only leaf nodes.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean [alpha-beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)?

Answer (score 0):

What about transposition table, principle variation search, aspiration windows, killer move heuristic, MVV-LVA ordering, quiescence search, draw detection, etc?

Well, here are the results for my own engine written in C#. This is with the starting position, a hash size of 64 MB (where enabled), and a i5-3570K processor.

```
Features                  Depth      Nodes
------------------------------------------------
Only alpha-beta,          8          78978022
iterative deepening,
simple evaluation

Enable everything         10         54612007
mentioned above, no 
pruning or reductions

Normal search             19         52000004
```

I expected the second result to be much greater actually (maybe depth 13). Yes, the full search relies heavily on late move reductions and the null move heuristic, but I think that if you had just a basic search the result would be around +5 depth, not +9. Lots of components are complements, and amplify each others' effectiveness.

Comment: Principle variation search and negascout are identical algorithms, aren't they? So it looks like your implementation is much faster. If you replace your quiescence with a simple evaluation, what depth do you get then. Quiescence search looks like a capture extension to me. I don't know if you use null move (pruning) but that should be excluded too for comparison purposes

Comment: I do not use zobrist keys in transposition table so could that make such a huge difference ?! Zobrist keys may give collisions. I use a somewhat larger key.

Comment: You get such a  depth of 19 due to LMR, isn't it. I do not understand LMR. It assumes almost perfect move ordering. Good move ordering costs too much CPU time, I think. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Actually the question should be what ELO rating is possible in chess using only one thread and no pruning, reductions, extensions or assembly language ? That would make comparison easier. But implementing a good ELO test is a lot of work, I guess.

Comment: @Henk Yes, I thought you wrote negamax. I think quiescence may actually help search depth as it prevents fluctuations and obviously incorrect PVs. Yes, LMR and null move have a huge effect on search depth. Good move ordering is very important, but LMR is usually beneficial purely because of greater depth. And if want to restrict everything to a basic search then strength is entirely based on the evaluation function, and we regress into the state of computer chess a few decades ago.

Comment: I actually do not understand LMR. It checks the last moves on level N but if for instance one of these moves wins a piece on level N + 1 that move is overlooked. Things get worse if the move that is overlooked was the only good move and the other moves loose the game.

Comment: @Henk Yes, there is always a search horizon. There is always the possibility, even on the deepest line, that the next move changes everything. But why explore all lines with equal effort if we can use certain heuristics (move ordering) to do better? The same number of nodes are searched, but we get a tree that has a different shape that better corresponds to how the game should be looked at given our metrics.